# Does Celery Automatically Monkey Patch when running eventlet pool?

Tags: python, django, celery, eventlet

This is a cross-post from the mailing list, hoping to get more eyes on the question. ([original post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/celery-users/sRAsr6pUqTA))

When using running `celery worker -p eventlet`, does Celery do automatic monkey-patching of my code?

The [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/concurrency/eventlet.html#concurrency-eventlet) don't mention anything about having to do patching and the [official example](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/examples/eventlet/tasks.py) doesn't do any explicit patching as well (even the [gevent example](https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/master/examples/gevent) doesn't do any patching). The example [hints](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/examples/eventlet/celeryconfig.py#L5-L7) at patching being done automatically, but there is no explicit/definite answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you run `celery worker` the function [`execute_from_commandline`](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/bin/base.py#L295) calls [`celery.__init__.maybe_patch_concurrency`](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/__init__.py#L112) which calls [`_patch_eventlet`](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/__init__.py#L91) which does:

```
def _patch_eventlet():
    import eventlet
    import eventlet.debug

    eventlet.monkey_patch()
    blockdetect = float(os.environ.get('EVENTLET_NOBLOCK', 0))
    if blockdetect:
        eventlet.debug.hub_blocking_detection(blockdetect, blockdetect)
```